# How to append Id of a component based on particular condition using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

i need to change the **id** of a component based on condition/flag, how can i achieve this using JQuery(any Script)? my component is like below.
 (below code written `XHTML`)

```
<p:txtLnkColumn id="c1" value="#{ROW.name}" editable="false"/>
```

in the above `id="c1"` change to `id="c2"` based on a condition.
is there any way to do that? (using any script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#c1').filter( function(){
    return condition == true;
}).attr('id','c2');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
if (condition) {
  $('#c1').attr('id', 'c2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. maybe `$('#c1').attr('id','c2')` you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try attr Jquery function?
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will do it automatically for ya using jQuery and a bit of regex.  Basically it expects an alpha prefix and a numeric postfix  (something like ccc111 will become ccc112):

```
function incrementId(element){
  id = element.attr("id");

  prefix = id.substr(0, id.search(/\d/)); 
  number = id.substr(id.search(/\d/), id.length-1);
  newId = prefix + (Number(number)+1).toString();

  element.attr("id", newId);
}
```

You could easily modify it to suit your condition/flag

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gVN6d/